# VB.Net Custom ListBox output issue

Tags: vb.net, listbox, custom-controls

Since i needed to disable (grey out) some items inside a ListBox, i'm using a Custom control that can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85079/Custom-List-Box-Control-with-Enable-Disable-Items):

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dtp.Columns.Add("key")
        dtp.Columns.Add("value")
        PopulateDataTable(dtp, "myTxt")

        _dataView = New DataView(dtp)

        'Custom ListBox
        List1.ValueMember = "key"
        List1.DisplayMember = "value"
        List1.DataSource = _dataView

        'Legacy ListBox
        List2.ValueMember = "key"
        List2.DisplayMember = "value"
        List2.DataSource = _dataView


        UpdateLanguageMenu()
    End Sub

    Private Function PopulateDataTable(dt As DataTable, resTxt As String)
        Using sw As New StringReader(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resTxt))
            Do
                Dim line As String = sw.ReadLine
                If line Is Nothing OrElse line.Trim = String.Empty Then Exit Do
                Dim strArr() As String
                strArr = line.Split(",")

                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                row("key") = strArr(0)
                row("value") = strArr(1)
                dt.Rows.Add(row)
            Loop
            sw.Close()
        End Using
    End Function
```

`List1` is the Custom ListBox and `List2` is the ListBox that comes with VS2012E.

I don't need `List2`, it's only there to test,
and at runtime, in `List2` i get all my values loaded correctly, instead in `List1` i get `System.Data.DataRowView` in all rows..

The strange thing is that, my txt i'm loading is like:

```
00A1,MyValue1
00A2,Myvalue2
00A3,MyValue3
```

I have also a Label, and when selecting items on the ListBox i have code to change the `Label.Text` to `List.SelectedValue` that is the first part before the comma.

And it get displayed in the label. Only items inside the Custom ListBox are not being displayed.

Populating `List1` manually, instead using a DataTable, is working.

And since i'm a beginner i can't locate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with this line: string displayValue = GetItemText(item); in the control. This takes for granted that all items are strings. In your case it is a datarowview hence the result (drv.toString would return something like that). You need to convert "item" into a drv and set display value to be drvItem("value" or "key") instead. So it is basically not your code that is the problem, it is the control.

Actually... After reading the code in the control and not on the code project site, I realised that this line:

```
displayValue = GetItemText(item);
```

Doesn't even exist. It is exchanged with

```
item.ToString()
```

Which pretty much proves my theory.

Right, how to fix.

In:

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
```

You have this:

```
object item = this.Items[e.Index];
```

What you have to do is to convert item into a DataViewRow and assign value to a variable, something like this:

```
DataViewRow dvrItem = (DataViewRow)item;
String displayText = dvrItem("key"); or String displayText = dvrItem("value");
```

Then change all these:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ToString(), e.Font, SystemBrushes.GrayText, e.Bounds);
```

Into:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(displayText, e.Font, SystemBrushes.GrayText, e.Bounds);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  While searching i found the developer site, and he said that the problem was that line. I searched for it and could't find it. What i need to change to make it working? Thank you

Comment: Edited it for you. Might not be 100% but it will help you atleast.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this solution is not a global fix, it is very specific to how you use it.